# jQuery slide div from bottom going wrong in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, animation, google-chrome

I have written my own image slider in jQuery that slides up a caption div from the bottom of the image.

Please see the demo on the following link: http://beta.marhaba.co.nz/about

When viewing this page in Google Chrome, you will notice how the caption div does not appear from the bottom of the image, but from below the image. To best understand what I am describing please see the link I have posted.

How do I fix this behaviour? Please note that the caption div has a height: auto.

I currently animate the caption div as follows:

```
$('.caption-container', $(this)).effect('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 'fast');
```

Comment: CSS can be see at: http://beta.marhaba.co.nz/sites/beta.marhaba.co.nz/themes/marhaba/css/barackslideshow.css

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the issue here is your CSS, not your JavaScript. Could you try setting the following CSS?

```
div#barak ul.pictures {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I think that will stop the caption from showing below the slideshow.

Comment: In Google Chrome, that has fixed the glitching of the caption, however, the caption wrapper div no longer slides up from the bottom as an animate.

Also just noticed that the CSS is not making the Javascript effect look right in IE.

See the update page on the same link - http://beta.marhaba.co.nz/about

Comment: Ok, perhaps you could try using the animate function and an absolute position?

You'll need to position the caption absolute for this to work.

$('.caption-container', $(this)).animate({ top: "xxxpx" }, 500 );